# How does React call the render function of an ES6 class in a such a way that `this` does not refer to the class itself?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, ecmascript-6, this

For example, given the class with a function increaseQty

```
increaseQty() {
  this.qty++
}
```

and the call

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.increaseQty}>Increase</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this.qty will be undefined unless I write a line in my constructor binding the context of `this` in the constructor to the function

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.qty = 0
  this.increaseQty = this.increaseQty.bind(this) // <---- like so
}
```

However this isn't the case in a normal es6 class if you're just using it normally:

https://jsfiddle.net/omrf0t20/2/

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.qty = 0
  }

  increaseQty() {
    console.log(++this.qty)
  }

  doStuff() {
    this.increaseQty()
  }
}

const t = new Test()
t.doStuff() // prints 1
```

What aspect of React makes it so that `render` is called without the context of `this`?

Comment: *"this isn't standard yet"* Arrow functions were included in the ES6 specification that was standardized last year. They're not going anywhere.

Comment: @JeremyBanks you're correct, but that's unrelated to this. What I'm currently talking about is a stage-1 proposal https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties

Comment: `this`, if not bound specifically, is bound to the caller. Since Javascript has prototypal inheritance, the caller could be anybody who has inherited the function from a prototype, or the prototype of a prototype, etc. So the advantage is flexibility. You don't always want that though, which is what `bind` is for.

Comment: How are you calling the increaseQty() method such that this.qty is undefined?

Comment: @nnnnnn a good example for now would be how lux calls `this.decreaseQty` in his render function. I'll edit it into my question and add a fiddle.

Comment: @nnnnnn turns out the entire premise of my question was flawed...this only really applies to React, which calls increaseQty in such a way that this.qty is undefined.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that that was the case. That's why I wanted to see a full example. It's not necessarily *only* React. But in general methods created with `class` syntax behave like the old-school syntax of creating via FunctionName.prototype.methodName =... And that means that unless you use .bind() there are several ways to change what `this` will be at the time of the invocation.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm going to edit it a bit, and try to salvage the question since I can't delete it. Perhaps you can answer it now.

Comment: @AR7 Just to clarify. Are you asking why it is necessary to declare 'this.qty = 0' on the constructor in order for the method 'this.increaseQty' to work? Or are you encountering a situation where you must bind this to the 'this.increaseQty' manually in order to get access to 'this.qty'?

Comment: @KennethMoore the second one specifically with react

Comment: (I don't really know React but I assume that) Your React render call is failing for the same reason that  passing a reference to that method in any callback situation would fail. E.g. `setTimeout(this.increaseQty, 10)` fails the same way. In JS, "methods" don't really belong to objects, a "method" is just an object property that references a function and in your render code you're passing a reference to the function, not the object.

Comment: The phenomenon has nothing to do with React, it's simply how `this` works in JavaScript. Have a look at the [MDN page about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @FelixKling yeah it was late at night for me, and I wasn't really thinking straight. I understand that the context of this changes inside the onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that in your example with React you are passing `increaseQty` as a callback to another component, but in the second, you are calling it within the current context.

You can see the difference here in simplified example

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.qty = 0
  }

  increaseQty() {
    console.log(++this.qty)
  }

  doStuff() {
    this.increaseQty(); // no need to bind
  }

  listenClicks() {
    // you should use bind to preserve context
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.increaseQty.bind(this)); 
  }
}
```

React guidelines also recommend you bind methods in the constructor, to make the code more optimal, bind it once and always use the same function rather than create a new bound version for each `render()` call.

Comment: I don't know how it slipped my mind that addEventListener changes the context of `this` thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really an ES6 specific question (other than the fact that we are referencing a class and constructor). What you're doing in your function is just incrementing a value. If that value has not been initialized to something (even in ES5) then it will throw an error. You can't add 1 to `undefined`.

In ES5 (and ES6 really) this would be a problem:

```
var myObj = {
    addOne: function() {
        this.qty++;
    }
}

myObj.addOne(); // Error! this.qty is undefined
```

Whereas this would resolve it:

```
var myObj = {
    qty: 0,
    addOne: function() {
        this.qty++;
    }
}

myObj.addOne(); // Good to go
```

It's the same situation in your class. You cannot increment a variable that you haven't declared and initialized to a number value.

In an even simpler example this:

```
var x;

x++;
```

would throw an error whereas this:

```
var x = 0;

x++;
```

is good.

Comment: Notice that you didn't have to do anything resembling `myObj.addOne = myObj.addOne.bind(myObj)`. You're not really addressing my question. Even if `this.qty` is defined in the constructor, if you don't bind `this` to the function `increaseQty`, it will have an undefined `this`.